# How add icon to dotnet desktop (Windows) application?

Tags: windows, .net-core

I have only used the `dotnet` line commands, both to generate projects and to generate "solutions" (`.sln`), however I don't know if it is possible to use `resource.rc` directly with`dotnet` with something like:

```
MAINICON  ICON  "icon.ico"
```

The question is, how can I add with `resource.rc` (or other means) an icon for a standard .NET-core application?

Will I need any tools other than `dotnet` (CLI) for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Today I did a test and apparently the tag works on `netcoreapp3.1`:

```
<ApplicationIcon>nome.ico</ApplicationIcon>
```

Obviously the project has to be an application, in my case I created a "console" application like this:

```
mkdir projeto1
cd projeto1
dotnet new console
```

So I was generated `projeto1.csproj`, I opened it and edited this way:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon>nome.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

So then I ran dotnet run and using both the c Debug and c Release flags (and publish also) this works, the example I did:

> [image: icon in csproj project for net core]

So I ran `dotnet build` and got the desired one:

> [image: executable with icon]